# Where does this `webpack://` come from for `webpack-dev-middleware`?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web, reactjs, webpack

I'm using https://github.com/gaearon/react-transform-boilerplate.

When I view the source code in Chrome, I saw a source is called `webpack://` (see the picture below)

[image]

However, when I access the URL such as `webpack:///src/App.js?14b1`. I find the file is not accessible.

Does anyone have ideas about where does this `webpack://` sources come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This the result of [webpack sourcemaps](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-devtoolmodulefilenametemplate) having been resolved in the browser.

Source maps provide a mapping between bundled and unbundled code.  By convention, webpack sourcemaps places a `webpack://` to *namespace* a resolved piece of unbundled code.

Once the webpack sourcemaps are produced (usually a file named `<name>.js.map`), you can open the `.js.map` file and see that values in the the `sources` property are prefixed with `webpack://`.  This is the *source root* for sourcemaps configured by webpack.